# Parametricity in Haskell

Tags: haskell

In my Haskell learning journey, I can't help but notice that parametricity is of the utmost importance in the language. Given how the type system and the inference capability of the compiler works, i think it is safe to say that parametricity or parametric polymorphism is natural, encourage and at the core of the philosophy of the language.

While the question I am going to ask is not specific to Haskell and could be ask to almost any programming language community, I'm quite intrigued at the point of view of the Haskellers, given the nature of the language as suggested above.

Why is parametricity so important to Haskellers? The language does really encourage to code to generic type and somewhat let the compiler figure out the right type when it is the most appropriate time (when it is forced too). Granted one does not have to stick to that, and we can and it is probably a good practice to declare the type.

But somehow I have the  feeling, the all thing encourage you to be generic and not focus on the concrete type at first, adding the capability  you need to the signature through type class, and focus on the composition and delay the concrete type at last, or leave it to the compiler.

I'm not completely sure of what I am saying but it feels that way.

I'm probably biased because I read a book in Scala, that also encourage that, although it is way more manual activity to than in Haskell.

Any philosophical response to that maybe? I have some idea about it, but from your point of you, how parametricity help programming faster and maybe safer too?

*Note: I'm a Scala programmer learning Haskell*

### Edit

I illustrate my propos as I am studying with "Programming Haskell from first principles". To cite the author:

> "There are some caveats to keep in mind here when it comes to using
> concrete types. One of the nice things about parametricity and type
> classes is that you are being explicit about what you mean to do with
> your data, which means you are less likely to make a mistake. Int is a
> big datatype with many inhabitants and many type classes and
> operations defined for it—it would be easy to make a function that
> does something unintended. Whereas if we were to write a function,
> even if we have Int values in mind for it, that uses a polymorphic
> type constrained by the type class instances we want, we could ensure
> we only use the operations we intend. This isn’t a panacea, but
> sometimes it can be worth avoiding concrete types for these (and
> other) reasons.
>
> (Page 208). "

I'd like to know what are the other reasons .... I mean this parametricity when compare to Scala that has it way more manual, is so baked in the language, I can't help think that is is part of the productivity philosophy of the language.

Comment: I'm voting to close as opinion-based, but here's my opinion: yes, parametric polymorphism is super helpful, because a polymorphic function can be reused in more contexts than an equivalent monomorphic one.

Comment: What a shame, i think it would have helped a lot of people. It may be opinionated but it is fundamental that people know how to use the tool they have at their disposal. That is why i am learning haskell as a scala programmer. I feel the need to ground my functional theorethical foundation. Understand the why and benefit.

Comment: Try https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I strongly disagree that this is opinion-based. The actual consequences of parametricity are not an opinion at all.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Maybe you can let it pass and see how it goes. I also think that this is not an opinion thing, there is a reason why it exist and why it is encourage as such, beside i give a specific citation from the author. There are clear consequences of at haskell being designed the way it is, and backing parametricity the way it is. "It did not happen by random chance, so we can have opinion about its usefulness ..." I am just trying to unearth what would take maybe months of practice to start seesing it clearly.

Comment: "Any philosophical response to that maybe?" is _definitely_ off-topic. If this were reworded and focused, sure, it might be on-topic, but at the moment it isn't. IMO an on-topic version of this is probably two or three sentences. SO isn't a blog.

Comment: Will work that out tomorrow :) ! Will narrow as much as I can. Beside the phylosophical statement is just rethorical ! In the end, it just means what was the drive behind that level or ease with parametricity. I certainly do not want to work in Haskell the wrong way because I got the wrong background. I want to be able to work the way it is intended to be used so I can get full advantage of the approach !

Comment: Spelling correction: in 16 of your posts, you are writing "trough" when you mean "through". Since "trough" is a correctly-spelled word with another meaning (a long open feeding container for animals) it will not be caught by a spell checker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parametricity is important because it restricts the implementation space. It's often the case that a properly parametric type restricts the implementation space down to a single implementation that lacks bottoms. Consider `fst :: (a, b) -> a`, for instance. With that type, there is only one possible return value from the function that doesn't have bottoms in it.

There are a lot of ways to write it that have bottoms - `undefined`, `error`, infinite loops, all of which varying in terms of eta expansion of the definition and whether the pair's constructor is matched. Many of these differences can be observed externally by careful means, but the thing they all have in common is that they don't produce a usable (non-bottom) value of type `a`.

This is a strong tool for implementing a definition. Given the guarantees parametricity makes, it's actually sufficient to test only that `fst ((), ()) == ()`. If that expression evaluates to `True`, the implementation is correct. (Ok, it's not quite that simple in ghc, given the ability to break all sorts of rules with unsafe functions. You also need to validate that the implementation doesn't use anything unsafe that breaks parametricity.)

But guiding the implementation is only the first benefit. A consequence of the implementation being so limited is that parametricity also turns the type into concise, precise, and machine-checked documentation. You know that no matter what the implementation is, the only non-bottom value it can return is the first element of the pair.

And yes - usually things aren't quite so constrained as in the type of `fst`. But in every case where parametric polymorphism is present in a type, it restricts the implementation space. And every time the implementation space is restricted, that knowledge serves as machine-checked documentation of implementation of the type.

Parametricity is a clear win for both the implementor and user of code. It reduces the space for incorrect implementations and it improves precision and accuracy of documentation. This should be as close to an objectively good thing as there is in programming.